# why is my res.status showing nothing when I console log it?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm trying to check a login form with passport js and I want that when the status is correct, to log the user in but when it is incorrect to return him to the login page. I've tried doing this with an if else statement but it is not working as I've tried to console log the status and it shows nothing.

This is my frontend:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './login.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";


function Login() {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)

    const history = useHistory()


    const onChangeUsername = (e) => {
      setUsername(e.target.value)
    }

    const onChangePassword = (e) => {
      setPassword(e.target.value)
    }

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()

      const users = {
        username: username,
        password: password
      }
      axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users/login', users)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    }

    const loginUser = () => {
      axios.get("http://localhost:4000/users/login", {
        withCredentials: true
      }).then(res => {
        if(res.status === 200) {
          setData(res)
          return history.push("/home")
        }
        else if(res.status === 400) {
          return history.push("/login")
      }
          console.log(res.status)
      })
    }

    return (
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/twitter-logo-png/twitter-logo-vector-png-clipart-1.png" className="twitterlogo____image"/>
          <h1 className="login_____headertext">Log in to Twitter</h1>
          <div className="placeholder_____global">
          <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <input className="placeholder____div" placeholder="Phone, email or username" onChange={onChangeUsername}/>
            <div>
              <input className="placeholder____div" placeholder="Password" type="password" onChange={onChangePassword}/>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button className="twitter___loginbuttonpage" onClick={loginUser}>Log in</button>
            </div>
            </form>
            <div className="forgetPassword_____div">
              <p>Forgot password?</p>
              <p>·</p>
              <p>Sign up for Twitter</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Server side code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Users = require('../models/users.model.js')
const passport = require("passport")

require('../authentication/passportConfig.js')(passport)


router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  Users.find()
    .then(users => res.json(users))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error:' + err))
})


router.route('/login').post((req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local" , (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!user) res.status(400).send("No user exists");
    else {
      req.logIn(user, err => {
        if (err) throw error;
        res.status(200).send("Succesfully Authenticated")
      })
    }
  })(req, res, next)
})

router.route('/login').get((req, res) => {
  res.send(req.user)
})

router.route('/add').post(async(req,res) => {
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
  const username = req.body.username
  const password = hashedPassword
  const email = req.body.email
  const phone = req.body.phone
  const monthOfBirth = req.body.monthOfBirth
  const dayOfBirth = req.body.dayOfBirth
  const yearOfBirth = req.body.yearOfBirth

  const newUsers = new Users({
    username,
    password,
    email,
    phone,
    monthOfBirth,
    dayOfBirth,
    yearOfBirth
  })

  newUsers.save()
  .then (() => res.json("User Added"))
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json('error' + err))
})



module.exports = router
```

Comment: It shows nothing because you have two `return` statements before your `console.log`, so it's returning early and never getting to that line.

Answer (score 0):

Before reaching `console` you are returning the control in `if` `else` conditions.
move your `console.log` before `if` `else`.

```
const loginUser = () => {
      axios.get("http://localhost:4000/users/login", {
        withCredentials: true
      }).then(res => {
        console.log(res.status)
        if(res.status === 200) {
          setData(res)
          return history.push("/home")
        }
        else if(res.status === 400) {
          return history.push("/login")
      }
      })
    }
```